# Puppet get root partition name using facter

Tags: puppet, facter

I am trying to get a root partition `(mount => "/")` name using Puppet facter.
When I run "`facter partitions`", it shows three partitions. 
I would like to get the variable "sda3" from the result.

```
{
  /dev/sda1 => {
    size => "1.00 MiB",
    size_bytes => 1048576
  },
  /dev/sda2 => {
    filesystem => "ext2",
    mount => "/boot",
    size => "477.00 MiB",
    size_bytes => 500170752,
    uuid => "8345d60e-e09a-4723-b5a6-149f4002706d"
  },
  /dev/sda3 => {
    filesystem => "ext4",
    mount => "/",
    size => "49.71 GiB",
    size_bytes => 53376712704,
    uuid => "a1330fb2-7f13-417e-8908-813b1fdae911"
  },
```

I tried `$hddname = $facts['partitions']['mount'] == "/"`, but got an error.
Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with hashes and arrays, you probably want the Puppet [Iteration and loops](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_iteration.html) features. That page links to a few useful functions and will help you find which you need.

First you need to *filter* the input:

```
$root_partition = $facts['partitions'].filter |$device, $partition| { $partition['mount'] == '/' }
```

This will assign the entire /dev/sda3 hash to `$root_partition`, equivalent to `{"/dev/sda3" => {"filesystem" .... }}`.

Then extract the device name from the single hash key left using the `keys` function from [stdlib](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib):

```
$hddname = keys($root_partition)[0]
```